# Regular expression to Extract substring

Tags: regex

I have a string like below

```
url('/testProject/Images/Current/Universal/Styles/MasterPage_HomeIcon.gif') repeat-x
```

How can I extract the substring starting from ' to end ' ?
I am using language as C#

Comment: What string below? It's missing from your question...

Comment: You should mention which language / regex library you'll be using.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the surrounding text:

```
/url\(('[^']+')\)/
```

If the surrounding text does not matter:

```
/('[^']+')/
```

The `[^']` selects all characters except the closing quote.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want `'` to be part of the matched group:

```
/'([^']*)'/
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this? (Assuming PCRE)

```
/(\'.*\')/
```