# Extract substring from a string in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, substring

I am looking to write some VBA code to obtain the following pieces of information from the following string with brackets and hyphens, i.e.

> ACOST 2012 Pricing Table - (PRJ 216664 - Financial Server Decommission) - 12 Month Term

Using VBA for Excel 2007, I need to obtain the following two bits within this string and assigned to two different variables, i.e.:

- 216664
- Financial Server Decommission

I tried the `Mid()` syntax but couldn't extract these two bits of info.

Comment: Is the format always going to be like that i.e (xxx xxxxxx - xxxxxxxxxxxxx)

Comment: Numerous related questions already exist on SO. Ex: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1624387/190829), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10903394/190829), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6052337/190829)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout - yes, the format will always be in this fashion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the format is going to remain same then you can use this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim strSample As String

    strSample = "ACOST 2012 Pricing Table - (PRJ 216664 - Financial Server Decommission) - 12 Month Term"
    strSample = Split(Split(strSample, "(")(1), ")")(0)

    Debug.Print Trim(Split(Split(strSample, "-")(0), " ")(1))
    Debug.Print Trim(Split(strSample, "-")(1))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way;

```
Data = "ACOST 2012 Pricing Table - (PRJ 216664 - Financial Server Decommission) - 12 Month Term"

dim re As object, matches as object: Set re = createobject("vbscript.regexp")
re.pattern="- \(.*?(\d+)\s+-\s+(.*?)\)(\s|$)"

with re.Execute(Data)
    msgBox  .item(0).SubMatches(0) & " / " & .item(0).SubMatches(1)
End with
```

> Get the last group of digits after "- (" before a "-" surrounded by
>   whitespace then get everything upto the next ) thats followed by
>   whitespace or the end of the line"